# R:Having unique rows except one cell, how to get unique rows keeping the differencies

Tags: r

I'm working on some data like these:

```
df <- data.frame(
      point = c('a','b','b','c'),
      value =c(1,2,2,3),
      x_p2=c(5,6,6,7),
      y_p2 =c(3,4,4,3),
      date =c(1,4,4,7),
      variable =c(4,3,3,1),
     other =c('x','zz','zk','x')
                )

> df
  point value x_p2 y_p2 date variable other
1     a     1    5    3    1        4     x
2     b     2    6    4    4        3    zz
3     b     2    6    4    4        3    zk
4     c     3    7    3    7        1     x
```

As you can see, each row is unique, except the second row and the third, those are different only for the `other` column. 
What I'd like to have is to have a result like unique, but merging the not common results: to be more clear, I'd like to have this result:

```
  point value x_p2 y_p2 date variable other
1     a     1    5    3    1        4     x
2     b     2    6    4    4        3    zz/zk
3     c     3    7    3    7        1     x
```

I tried with the `unique()` function, but clearly it takes the first not equal rows, and my rows are all different in each column, furthermore it does not "melt" the other field that is different, and I'd like to keep that. 
I do not know how to figure it (neither the title of this question to be honest). WHat do you advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `dplyr`

```
df%>%group_by( point,value,x_p2,y_p2,date,variable)%>%dplyr::summarise(other=paste(other,collapse='/'))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   point, value, x_p2, y_p2, date [?]
   point value  x_p2  y_p2  date variable other
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
1      a     1     5     3     1        4     x
2      b     2     6     4     4        3 zz/zk
3      c     3     7     3     7        1     x
```

Comment: Can also use `group_by_at(vars(-other))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option with `merge` and `unique`.  Get the `unique` rows by removing the last column, and `merge` with the `paste`ed 'other' `aggregated` by 'point'

```
merge(unique(df[-ncol(df)]), aggregate(other ~ point, df, paste, collapse="/"))
#  point value x_p2 y_p2 date variable other
#1     a     1    5    3    1        4     x
#2     b     2    6    4    4        3 zz/zk
#3     c     3    7    3    7        1     x
```

---

If we wanted to keep as a `list` column, this can be done wth `summarise`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(names(.)[1:6])) %>% 
    summarise(other = list(other))
```

Or with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(other ~ ., df, I)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 aggregate(df,list(do.call(paste,df[-7])),function(x)unique(x))[-1]
  point value x_p2 y_p2 date variable  other
1     a     1    5    3    1        4      x
2     b     2    6    4    4        3 zz, zk
3     c     3    7    3    7        1      x
```